# How to implement an interface which has been parameterized and extends two other interfaces?

Tags: java, interface

I've got three interfaces:

```
public interface IAggregable<TElement extends IAggregable<TElement, TResult>, TResult> {
    TResult aggregate(TResult intermediateResult);
}

public interface IDeeplyCloneable<TElement extends IDeeplyCloneable<TElement>> {
    TElement deepClone();
}

public interface IContainer<TElement extends IAggregable<TElement, TResult> & IDeeplyCloneable<TElement>, TResult> {
    TResult aggregateAllElements();
    TElement cloneElementAtIndex(int index);
}
```

I try to implement the last one by;

```
public class GTZCH<TElement, TResult> implements IContainer<TElement, TResult> {

    public GTZCH() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public TResult aggregateAllElements() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public TElement cloneElementAtIndex(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

but I get an compilation error:

```
Bound mismatch: The type TElement is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <TElement extends 
 IAggregable<TElement,TResult> & IDeeplyCloneable<TElement>> of the type IContainer<TElement,TResult>
```

What does `&` operator means in the exends part, I thought there should be a coma not & to extend multiple interfaces.

How to implement that interface the way I will not have to use raw type?

Comment: It is an `&` in type constraints. See [the tutorial on type bounds](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should use an & in type constraints and define the bound of your TElement when declaring GTZCH:

```
public class GTZCH<TElement extends IAggregable<TElement,TResult> & IDeeplyCloneable<TElement>, TResult> implements IContainer<TElement, TResult> {
    [...]
}
```